# Rails 4.2.2 - How to use ancestry gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jstree, ancestry

In rails 4.2.2, I am using `jstree` and `ancestry` gems for folder and files structure. How can I use ancestry methods in our model? Please give some examples with full model structure. I have already tried it by referring this `https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry`, but I don't know whether generated result is correct or not.

Please help me to create ancestry model structure and how can I use it for jstree.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't used it before, I'd suggest just building a tree in rails console like have a Header class that has `name` (and obviously `ancestry`) and do (off the top of my head):

```
class Header < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
end

> h1=Header.create name:"h1"
> h2=Header.create name:"h2", parent: h1
> h1.reload
> h1.children
> h3=Header.create name:"h2", parent: h2
> h1.reload
> h1.children
```

That will start you with the basics of how the gem works

Comment: Thank You. This is working fine but how can I call this ancestry data to a jstree dynamically?

Comment: not familiar with jstree but I use has_children? and a recursive call if there are children. somthing like `renderChildren(children_nodes) `that gets called if you have children and if not returns the current value. Usually, you want a global string value that you are just continually appending to (or whatever underlying templating languare you are using such as Handlebars).